# org.apache.wicket.util.license.XmlLicenseHeaderHandler failed with IntelliJ

Tags: wicket

Compiling all wicket-examples out_of-off the github repo  I got an this message

> The following files(85) didn't have correct license header.

I don't know what is missing there.

Answer (score 0):

You can just ignore these failures. If the tests pass at command line: `mvn clean test` then everything is fine.

I guess the problem is that tests run with different/wrong "working directory" and thus the files which should be ignored could not be matched.